# how to get valid Date and Time instances using spring and thymeleaf

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i am using `thymeleaf` and `spring boot` in my project and i need to save `date` and 
`time` object in `mySql` database, this is how i have validated my entity class

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "sdate")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
private Date sdate; //represents start Date - i am passing 2014-01-01- this works fine.

@NotNull
@Column(name = "stime")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.TIME)
private Date stime; //represent start time - i am passing 12:10:20.444
```

when i am trying to get the values from `thymleaf` form to the `controller` i cant get a `valid` class it contain `errors`. is there something i am doing wrong with the `validation`  part. how can i get a `valid input` from the `form`.

```
 public String save(@ModelAttribute("travel") @Valid Travel travel,BindingResult result){
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            for (Object element : result.getAllErrors()) {
                System.out.println(element.toString());
            }
    }
```

error message :

```
Field error in object 'travel' on field 'stime': rejected value [12:10:20.444]
```

Comment: Have you tried [`pattern()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html#pattern--) for custom date time format?

Answer (score 1):

According to [spring document for DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#TIME), the right format for ISO.TIME is "12:10:20.444+00:00", where the "+00:00" part is the time zone offset (suppose that there is no offset for your time zone).

So you need to reformat your input to include the time zone offset in your time string.

Comment: Is it possible to change the type of stime to LocalTime (in this case, don't format your input with time zone offset)?

Comment: i cant change it to a localTIme im getting data truncation error.

Comment: Does that mean the validation error has been solved? and now you got truncation error when save data to MySQL? if so, is it possible to change the datatype of 'stime' column to TIME?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112216/discussion-between-dot-and-priyamal).